# Does anyone know how i center my mouse in the middle with python?

Tags: micropython, adafruit-circuitpython

*The problem I currently have is that the mouse pointer is in the middle bottom of my screen and I am not able to move it whatsoever. I need the mouse pointer in the middle of my screen so I can use it for cookie clicker.*

Edit: i am making this auto clicker with my raspberry pi pico.

**this is my code for an auto clicker for the Samsung Galaxy A70.**

```
import time
import usb_hid
from adafruit_hid.mouse import Mouse
import board
import digitalio

MIDDLE_BUTTON = 4
RIGHT_BUTTON = 2
LEFT_BUTTON = 1

mouse = Mouse(usb_hid.devices)
led = digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.GP25)
led.direction = digitalio.Direction.OUTPUT

led.value = False
time.sleep(25)
mouse.move(y=360)

while True:
        led.value = True
        mouse.click(mouse.LEFT_BUTTON)
        time.sleep(0.01)
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: Can you clarify what the hardware setup is here please - do you have a Raspberry Pi Pico running CircuitPython, connected by USB to a Galaxy A70, and you're trying to emulate a mouse with this CircuitPython code? As it stands now does your code click the mouse correctly, but not move the mouse pointer? Does it work when connected to a PC instead of the Galaxy?

Comment: i appreciate your detailed comment bro! i currently fixed my problem.

Comment: @rensschuil Please explain to us how you solved your problem, the steps you took, etc, so that other future visitors may gain helpful information from this post.

Comment: I didn't change my code. I plugged in my mouse and put the mouse cursor in the position I wanted and then removed the mouse. this way the cursor wouldn't change.